# http request by node-red with execution the stript

Tags: javascript, http, node-red

I would like ask,
When I use node http request from Node-red for request to any page it returned me whole page like

```
msg.payload="<'html>
<'script>
function A;
function B;
window.onload = function() {...
etc...
<'/script>
<'body>
<'table>"
```

How can I execute the functions from the script? So how it could return executed page to node-red?
I mean, I need the results from the fucntions and I get just function in payload, so I don't know how could I execute function which are in payload.

Thank you
Pavol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is, you don't.

Running JavaScript embedded in a web page needs all the things a browser provides to the page, e.g. the DOM model these are just not there in the Node-RED runtime.

If you want to load and render a page then you need to look at something like [node-red-contrib-nbrowser](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-nbrowser) that will run the page in a virtual browser.

Comment: Thank you very much. This nbrowser is everything what I need.